# Why are my Xamarin.Forms controls overlapping in my StackLayout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to design a login page using a StackLayout. I thought that each item is supposed to display linearly from top to bottom but for some reason the controls are overlapping. Here is my .xaml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DJB.Views.LoginPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DJB.Controls">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="djblogowithtext" Margin="30,30"></Image>
            <!-- UserName -->
            <Label Text="Username" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="15" Margin="1"/>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="1" Margin="30,0" HeightRequest="20">
                <local:TextEntry BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- Password -->
            <Label Text="Password" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="15" Margin="1"/>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="1" Margin="30,0" HeightRequest="20">
                <local:TextEntry BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Button Text="Login" Margin="30" BackgroundColor="#f7ebeb" Clicked="Login_Clicked"> </Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is what it looks like on Android:

[image]

I'm sure this is something really simple but I'm new to Xamarin.Forms so not sure why it's coming out like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are specifying Heights for the controls that are not big enough to fit their contents.  Either don't use one at all and let the controls size themselves, or use a value that is big enough for the content.

```
<Label Text="Username" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="15" Margin="1"/>
```

a Label with a default font probably needs a height of 30 or more, not 15

Comment: Thanks @Jason . I got rid of the height request lines and it looks fine now.